# Define a function to find largest number in a list

Tags: python

```
def maximum(l,n):
    maximum=l[0]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if (l[i]>maximum):
              max=l[i]
```

return maximum

l=[]

```
#main program

n=input("Enter size of list")
for i in range(0,n):
    num=input("Enter elements")
    l.append(num)
    lgt=maximum(l,n)
    print 'largest number is',lgt
```

This is the code guys....can you please tell where im wrong??

Comment: You don't seem to return anything, plus its confusing to name your temporary variables the same as your function, also are these typos: `max=l[i]`?

Comment: @EdChum yh sorry if forgot to put the return...edited. i dont understand what is typos...im sorry im a noob....im new to this site and python....could you please help me out a bit?

Comment: is it an error here: `max=l[i]` as this will not do anything, don't you want `maximum=[i]`?

Comment: Move the last two lines of your loop outside the loop, so they start at the same column as the `f` in `for`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid can we please not use the max function? i was told not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The `lgt=max(l)` and `print 'largest number is',lgt`  should be outside the for loop.

```
n=input("Enter size of list")
my_list=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    num=input("Enter elements")
    l.append(num)
lgt=max(my_list)
print 'largest number is',lgt
```

Now without using `max()` I think you can try the following code.

```
n=input("Enter size of list")
my_list=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    num=input("Enter elements")
    my_list.append(num)
my_list.sort()
print my_list
print 'largest number is',my_list[-1]
```

Now If you want to use your `maximum` function then try the following code.

```
def maximum(x):
    x.sort()
    return x[-1]

n=input("Enter size of list")
my_list=[]
for i in range(0,n):
    num=input("Enter elements")
    my_list.append(num)
print "The largest number is",maximum(my_list)
```

Comment: it definitely works i've tried but i dont want to use the max function....is it possible without it?

Comment: See my new edited code. Tell me if that code doesn't help you

Comment: could you explain a bit abt [-1] in the end?

Comment: i will1 but could you plz explain me abt the my_list[-1]?

Comment: `my_list[-1]` means the last element of the list. I have sorted the list before which means the last element will be containing the largest value.

Comment: you can slightly modify my code to return the largest value. And also you didn't use `maximum` function anywhere in your code.

Comment: could you please help me with a code using that maximum function please?

Comment: Oh! We are far from closing aren't we :)

Comment: yeah i guess we are :-P sorry abt that

Comment: Edited my code as you wanted. This time I'm closing :) once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
lgt=maximum(l,n)
```

you pass `n`, and it must be a length of list `l`. But, during iteration, length of list is smaller than final `n`. So, you'll get an `IndexError`

You don't need to implement `maximum` function by yourself, as python has builtin [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)

So, do like this:

```
n=input("Enter size of list")
for i in range(0,n):
    num=input("Enter elements")
    l.append(num)
    lgt=max(l)
    print 'largest number is',lgt
```

Comment: Ideally, you should put `max(l)` _outside_ the for loop, otherwise it will keep printing the max for as many elements are in the list.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes, but is it hard to say, what is needed: print max of all elements, or print max at every input

Comment: @stalk thanks im getting close but is there a way without the max function please?

Comment: @MadhavManohar yes, there is a way. Your function `maximum` doesn't need to take additional `n` argument, as length of list `l` can always be found by calling `len(l)`

Comment: @OK so how is the programming supposed to continue according to what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you don't need to know the length of a list to loop over it:

```
def maximum(some_list):
   maximum = 0
   for i in some_list:
      if i > maximum:
         maximum = i
   return maximum
```

Also, don't use `max` as name of your variables as this is a name of built-in function in Python. `l` is also a bad name for a variable because it looks like `1` in some fonts.

You also don't need to ask for the length of the list ahead of time:

```
numbers = []
n = 0

while n != 'N':
   n = input('Please enter a number, or N to stop: ')
   if n != 'N':
       numbers.append(n)

print('You entered {} numbers and the maximum is {}'.format(len(numbers), maximum(numbers)))
```